# unable to see 'master' branch on git in ubuntu16.04

Tags: git, github, git-branch

While using the command `git branch` it is not showing the "master" branch. Instead, I'm getting this:

> error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Comment: Is this a new repository?

Comment: Yes it is a new repo. I'm doing it in a new container on which git is installed.

Comment: What command are you running again?

Comment: When you got that error message what is the command you used ?

Comment: I have used 'git push origin master' in order to push my code to remote repo.